# Convert to date only when needed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I tried converting the strings to date, which works but:

| Original | Converted |
| --- | --- |
| 10/5/1983 | 1983-10-5 |
| 05/27/87 | 1987-05-27 |
| 3/10/1970 | 2070-03-10 |

↑↑↑ This is the error. Somehow some of the 19xx got converted to 20.

I have tried: `df['BirthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BirthYear'], format = ' %m-%d-%y')`.

The error is `ValueError: time data '10/7/1986' does not match format ' %m-%d-%y' (match)`.

Comment: `%d` expects a zero-padded date like `10/07/1986`.  Same for `%m`, it's expecting a zero-padded month.

Comment: You provide the format of original value, i.e. which value is which and how to parse it. Here `format` means the `format` of string in `Original` column.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are using hyphens instead of slashes which is what is in your data. Try

```
df['Birthyear'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Birthyear'], format='%m/%d/%y')
```

Comment: does `%Y` will consider the case of `05/27/87`?

Comment: @GodWin, you are right, I changed it to lowercase

Comment: Hi, tried that but it doesn't work for 3rd row (ie 1970 becomes 2070)

When I pull the row out, it says "70" <- data type is string
How do I convert? I plan to do a if else?

Comment: Could you try df['Birthyear'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Birthyear']